# Replace duplicated elements with NA, instead of removing them

Tags: r

I have a `DF`. One of its columns looks like

```
DF$A
A
    a
    a
    a
    b
    b
    b
    c
    c
```

I am trying to replace all duplicated characters in this column with `NA`.
Naively, I tried

```
DF$A <- DFl[duplicated(DF$A),] <- NA
```

But it just converts whole DF to `NA` values. Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: `DF$A[duplicated(DF$A)] <- NA`

Comment: `x <- rep(letters[1:3], c(3, 3, 2)); is.na(x) <- duplicated(x)` works fine for me.

Comment: Provide a reproducible example

Comment: @cory, i think you can turn it into an answer!?

Comment: @RichardScriven thank you, it worked. Please turn it to an answer, then i can vote and accept

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate.  You can feel free to use my comment for an answer.

Answer (score 14):

You were pretty close. I'm not sure what `DFl` is though. But this works...

```
DF <- data.frame(A=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"))
DF$A[duplicated(DF$A)] <- NA
> DF
     A
1    a
2 <NA>
3 <NA>
4    b
5 <NA>
6    c
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking the example from above, if you have a file with several columns, and you want to do the same for each column, you could use this:

```
 DF <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","a","c","b","c"),col2=c("b","c","c","c","a","a"))


for(i in 1:ncol(DF)){
  DF[,i][duplicated(DF[,i])] <- NA 
}
```