# R - find all duplicates in row and replace

Tags: r, duplicates, apply

I have a large dataframe and am trying find duplicate elements in a row and to then replace all duplicated values with an empty string :

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
x  1  2  3  3  4
y  1  1  2  3  4
```

should become

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
x  1  2        4
y        2  3  4
```

I'm able to do this on a single vector :

```
x <- c(1,2,3,3,4)
x[x %in% x[duplicated(x) == TRUE]] = ""
x

[1] "1" "2" ""  ""  "4"
```

But I am unable to get this to work over all rows in a dataframe.
I've tried the following but could not get it to work :

```
apply(df,2,function(x) x[x %in% x[duplicated(x) == TRUE]] = "")
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You have numeric data set and by replacing values by `""` the whole data set will be come characters. Do you really want that? You won't be able to do arithmetic operation any more. Also, I would consider working with matrices in your place.

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, I want to make all of the values characters eventually.  I will look into your suggestion about using matrices. Thank you.

Comment: I think there are gazzillions of dupe for this problem. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306011/replace-duplicated-elements-with-na-instead-of-removing-them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {x[x==x[duplicated(x)]] <- ''; x})))
```

to get

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
x  1  2        4
y        2  3  4
```

If you want to retain the integer type for each column, try this:

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {x[x==x[duplicated(x)]] <- NA; x})))
```

to get

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
x  1  2 NA NA  4
y NA NA  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this,

Finding out the indices which are duplicates in a dataframe and replacing them with a blank space.

```
df[which(t(apply(df,1,function(x) 
     duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = T))), arr.ind = T)] <- ""

df
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#x  1  2        4
#y        2  3  4
```