# Is there any R function to find spaces between words?

Tags: r, function

I have data as below, I need to find out data where 1st and last name both are given and it should start with Dear. is there any R function for this?

1. Dear Amandeep Singh, kindly use
2. Congrats! Check for instant credit eligibility
3. Dear Rahul, kindly use
4. Dear Pooja Rathore, kindly use
5. Hi SHAILENDRA, welcome
6. Hi Ashok Kumar, welcome

I want output as below:

1. Dear Amandeep Singh, kindly use
2. Dear Pooja Rathore, kindly use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - find all duplicates in row and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034701/r-find-all-duplicates-in-row-and-replace)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of spaces after you remove the part of the string after the comma, i.e.

```
stringr::str_count(sub(', .*', '', x), ' ') == 2
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Use the above boolean to subset your vector, i.e.

```
x[stringr::str_count(sub(', .*', '', x), ' ') == 2]
#[1] "Dear Amandeep Singh, kindly use" "Dear Pooja Rathore, kindly use"
```

**DATA**

```
x <- c('Dear Amandeep Singh, kindly use', 'Dear Rahul, kindly use', 'Dear Pooja Rathore, kindly use')
```