# tidy way to remove duplicates per row

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I've seen different solutions to remove rowwise duplicates with base R solutions, e.g. [R - find all duplicates in row and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034701/r-find-all-duplicates-in-row-and-replace).

However, I'm wondering if there's amore tidy way. I tried several ways of using across or a combination of rowwise with c_across, but can't get it work.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 y = c(1, 3, 4, 5),
                 z = c(2, 3, 5, 6))
```

Expected output:

```
  x  y  z
1 1 NA  2
2 2  3 NA
3 3  4  5
4 4  5  6
```

My ideas so far (not working):

```
df |> 
  mutate(apply(across(everything()), 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), NA)))

df |> 
  mutate(apply(across(everything()), 1, function(x) {x[duplicated(x)] <- NA}))
```

I got somewhat along the way by creating a list column that contains the column positions of the duplicates (but it also has the ugly warning about the usual "new names" problem. I'm unsure how to proceed from there (if that's a promising way), i.e. I guess it requires some form of purrr magic?

```
df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(test = list(duplicated(c_across(everything())))) |> 
  unnest_wider(test)

# A tibble: 4 × 6
      x     y     z ...1  ...2  ...3 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1     1     2 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
2     2     3     3 FALSE FALSE TRUE 
3     3     4     5 FALSE FALSE FALSE
4     4     5     6 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Why is it "|>", not "%>%"?

Comment: It's the new base pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  do(data.frame(replace(., duplicated(unlist(.)), NA)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Rowwise: 
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    NA     2
2     2     3    NA
3     3     4     5
4     4     5     6
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Very neat!

Comment: Changed the package from `tidyverse` to `dplyr`. All used functions are in the dplyr package.

Comment: one follow-up question - how would this ideally look if I want to replace NA's only on a selection of columns, e.g. only among y and z?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say its tidy but it is a solution using `map`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_nest(row_number()) %>% 
  pull(data) %>% 
  map(function(x) as.numeric(x) %>% replace(., duplicated(.), NA) %>% setNames(names(df))) %>% 
  bind_rows()
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#       x     y     z
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    NA     2
# 2     2     3    NA
# 3     3     4     5
# 4     4     5     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, after trialing & erroring a bit, I also got the same result as provided by @Quinten, just in a much, much uglier way!

```
df |>
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(pos = list(which(duplicated(c_across(everything()))))) |> 
    mutate(across(-pos, ~ ifelse(which(names(df) == cur_column()) %in% unlist(pos), NA, .))) |> 
    select(-pos)
```

Comment: Also the `map` functions `purrr` can be of help in roowise operations

Comment: Yes, I'm just not sure how in this case.