# How to make next repeated values as a blank if the value appears greater then 3 times

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below. In the data frame the value "45" repeating/appears for "A" greater than 3 times and also same for "67" for "B", Now needs to make them  as "Blank/NA" for those which are repeating / frozen greater than 3 times ("New_value")

```
Name    Value   New_Value
 A       24      24
 A       45      45
 A       45      
 A       45      
 A       45      
 A       45      
 A       93      93 
 A       19      19
 A       10      10
 B       29      29
 B       67      67
 B       67         
 B       67      
 B       67      
 C      201     201
 C      993     993
 C      396     396
```

Comment: this has been already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306011/replace-duplicated-elements-with-na-instead-of-removing-them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace duplicated elements with NA, instead of removing them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306011/replace-duplicated-elements-with-na-instead-of-removing-them)

Comment: @Larusson, this is not a duplicated question. the poster needs to replace the data value showing up more than 3 times

Comment: All of the answers involving `duplicated` (ordinary or data.table) do not address the issue of repeating in sequence. And it's not clear, either, from the request whether the questioner understands that issue.

Comment: What do you expect if a `Value` is repeated exactly two times? Unfortunately, your sample data don't cover that case.

Comment: @42- Have posted an RLE based answer using an enhanced data set to cover more use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, here is another `data.table` solution using `rleid()` instead of `duplicated()`.

Note that the OP requested *to make next repeated values as a blank if the value appears greater then 3 times*. This implies that for a `Value` which is repeated exactly two times *no* blanks should appear in the result. I've amended my sample data set to include the case of exactly two repetitions of the same value.

**Edit**: The OP hasn't made it clear whether he is counting repetitions of the same `Value` in the given sequence regardless of `Name` or if he is counting repetitions in the sequence per `Name` group. See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971876/how-to-make-next-repeated-values-as-a-blank-if-the-value-appears-greater-then-3#comment74976470_43971876).

In addition, the OP hasn't specified what result he expects if there's a sequence of repeated `Value`s but with a change in `Name`.

Therefore, I've modified my sample data set to include the additional use cases as well:

```
DT
#    Name Value
# 1:    A    24
# 2:    A    24
# 3:    A    45
# 4:    A    45
# 5:    A    45
# 6:    A    45
# 7:    A    45
# 8:    A    93
# 9:    A    19
#10:    A    19
#11:    A    10
#12:    B    29
#13:    B    67
#14:    B    67
#15:    B    67
#16:    B    67
#17:    C   201
#18:    C   993
#19:    C   396
#20:    A    19
#21:    A    19
#22:    C    19
#23:    B    29
#24:    B    67
#25:    B    67
#26:    B    67
#27:    B    67
#28:    C    67
#29:    C    67
#30:    C    67
#31:    C    67
#    Name Value
```

As in the other answers, `NA` is taken for blank.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[, New := Value[.N < 3], by=rleid(Value)][rowid(rleid(Value)) == 1L, New := Value]
DT
#    Name Value New
# 1:    A    24  24
# 2:    A    24  24
# 3:    A    45  45
# 4:    A    45  NA
# 5:    A    45  NA
# 6:    A    45  NA
# 7:    A    45  NA
# 8:    A    93  93
# 9:    A    19  19
#10:    A    19  19
#11:    A    10  10
#12:    B    29  29
#13:    B    67  67
#14:    B    67  NA
#15:    B    67  NA
#16:    B    67  NA
#17:    C   201 201
#18:    C   993 993
#19:    C   396 396
#20:    A    19  19
#21:    A    19  NA
#22:    C    19  NA
#23:    B    29  29
#24:    B    67  67
#25:    B    67  NA
#26:    B    67  NA
#27:    B    67  NA
#28:    C    67  NA
#29:    C    67  NA
#30:    C    67  NA
#31:    C    67  NA
#    Name Value New
```

The first expression copies `Value` for all RLE groups with one or two repetitions. All RLE groups with more repetitions get `NA`. The second expressions copies `Value` only for the first row in each RLE group.

Note that each sequence of repeated values is treated separately regardless of `Name` but the change of `A` to `C` in row 22 and of`B` to `C` in row 27 is being ignored.

This can be further improved to copy only if not already copied:

```
setDT(DT)[, New := Value[.N < 3], by=rleid(Value)
          ][is.na(New) & rowid(rleid(Value)) == 1L, New := Value]
```

---

In case the change in `Name` is expected to "restart" `Value` as well this  variant could be used (credits to Jaap):

```
setDT(DT)[, New := Value[.N < 3], by = rleid(Name, Value)
          ][is.na(New) & rowid(rleid(Name, Value)) == 1L, New := Value][]
#    Name Value New
# 1:    A    24  24
# 2:    A    24  24
# 3:    A    45  45
# 4:    A    45  NA
# 5:    A    45  NA
# ...
#18:    C   993 993
#19:    C   396 396
#20:    A    19  19
#21:    A    19  19
#22:    C    19  19
#23:    B    29  29
#24:    B    67  67
#25:    B    67  NA
#26:    B    67  NA
#27:    B    67  NA
#28:    C    67  67
#29:    C    67  NA
#30:    C    67  NA
#31:    C    67  NA
#    Name Value New
```

Note the difference in rows 21, 22, and 27.

#### Data

```
DT <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Value = c(24L, 
24L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 93L, 19L, 19L, 10L, 29L, 67L, 67L, 
67L, 67L, 201L, 993L, 396L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 29L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 
67L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 67L)), .Names = c("Name", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note that rows 1 and 8 have been duplicated w.r.t. the OP's data set to cover the case of exactly two repetitions and that a fews rows have been added at the end.

Comment: `x := v[logi]` is a weird thing to do, I think. When `logi` is false, the RHS has zero length, which I would expect to break things... If it doesn't, then this is relying on a weird implementation quirk in my opinion. Anyway, I guess I'd expect to see `x := if (logi) v else v[NA_integer_]`

Comment: @Frank Since version 1.9.8, this is no longer weird: _A new column is guaranteed with `:=` even when there are no matches or when its RHS is length 0_ (see 2nd item in https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#potentially-breaking-changes).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Well, weirdness is subjective :) For the same reason, I like `if (logi) .SD` over `.SD[logi]`. Generally, both problems (in terms of strange/weird syntax) will disappear when there's https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/788

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` way to do that. I show two solutions, for

1. You look for duplicates within the `Names` group
2. You look for duplicates in all data

Here is the code:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Names = LETTERS[1:5] %>% sample(100, replace = TRUE),
                 Value = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))
dt <- dt[order(Names, Value)]

# if you look for in-group duplicates
dt[, count := .N, by = .(Names, Value)][, New_Value := Value]
dt[ , dup_ingroup := duplicated(Value), by = Names]
dt[dup_ingroup & count > 3, New_Value := NA]

# if you look for all duplicates
dt[, count := .N, by = Value][, New_Value := Value]
dt[duplicated(Value) & count > 3, New_Value := NA]
```

**NOTE**

For the comments below.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(20170515)
dt <- data.table(Names = LETTERS[1:5] %>% sample(100, replace = TRUE),
                 Value = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))
dt <- dt[order(Names, Value)]
dt_1 <- copy(dt)
dt_2 <- copy(dt) 
dt_Jaap <- copy(dt)
# Method 1
dt_1[, count := .N, by = .(Names, Value)][, New_Value := Value]
dt_1[ , dup_ingroup := duplicated(Value), by = Names]
dt_1[dup_ingroup & count > 3, New_Value := NA]
dt_1[, .N, by = is.na(New_Value)] 
## is.na  N
## 1: FALSE 73
## 2:  TRUE 27

# Method 2
dt_2[, count := .N, by = Value][, New_Value := Value]
dt_2[duplicated(Value) & count > 3, New_Value := NA]
dt_2[, .N, by = is.na(New_Value)] 
## is.na  N
## 1: FALSE 12
## 2:  TRUE 88

# Method suggested by @Jaap
dt_Jaap[, New_Value := Value][duplicated(Value) & .N > 3, New_Value := NA_integer_, by = .(Names, Value)]
dt_Jaap[, .N, by = is.na(New_Value)]  
## is.na  N
## 1: FALSE 10
## 2:  TRUE 90
```

The `dt_Jaap` just keeps the value of the first element of each value of `Value`.

Comment: You can make it shorter. For the in-group duplicates: `dt[, New_Value := Value][duplicated(Value) & .N > 3, New_Value := NA_integer_, by = .(Name, Value)]`. As you can see, you don't have to create the `count`-variable, you can use `.N` directly in `i`.

Comment: @Jaap, that seems not working because `duplicated(Value) & .N > 3` part is not grouped by `by` variables. the result of `dt[, .N, by = is.na(New_Value)]` is not the same for mine and yours.

Comment: It is giving me the correct output. Did you update to the latest version of `data.table` (*v1.10.4*)?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, you are correct. I thought that `.N` could now be used in `i`, but I couldn't find it in the news-file; so apparently that is not the case :-/

Answer (score -1):

and the `dplyr`/`tidyverse` way, assuming the order of the data frame does not matter...

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
                 Value = c(24,45,45,45,45,45,93,19,10,29,67,67,67,67,201,993,396,396,396),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Name, Value) %>% 
  mutate(New_Value = ifelse(n() > 3 & row_number() > 1, NA, Value))
```

**UPDATE**

a more robust way that can handle multiple sets of the same value...

```
df <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "
Name    Value
A       45
A       45
A       45
A       82
A       45
A       45
A       45
A       45
A       12
A       45
A       45
A       45
A       45
A       45
B       29
B       67
B       67
B       67
B       67
")

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(run_length = with(rle(Value), rep(lengths, lengths))) %>%
  mutate(run_start = seq_along(Value) %in% cumsum(c(1, rle(Value)$lengths))) %>%
  mutate(New_Value = ifelse(run_length < 4 | run_start, Value, NA)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-run_length, -run_start)
```

Comment: fixed a typo in the code... used `data` instead of `df` for the data frame name, but conceptually it's exactly the same

Comment: Please note that your solution will also add NA for the second value in case of exactly two repetitions of the same value. The OP has requested that blanks should only appear if a value is repeated three or more times. Unfortunately, the sample data set of the OP doesn't include the case of exactly two repetitions.

Comment: I missed that (>3 times) somehow on my first read. I updated my code to work (assuming the order of the rows in the data frame do not matter)