# Replace duplicated values in a column with blank

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, duplicates

For what I'm working with, I'm having difficult finding a solution whereby I can remove duplicate values **without deleting duplicate rows or even replacing the entire row**. What I want to do is take a data frame like:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
[1]1  2  5  6  7
[2]1  3  6  5  7 
[3]1  4  7  4  7
[4]2  1  3  3  6
[5]2  2  4  5  6
[6]3  1  2  2  5
[7]3  2  1  3  5
```

and rework it so it removes the duplicates in column E and replaces them with a blank value like so:

```
       A  B  C  D  E
    [1]1  2  5  6  7
    [2]1  3  6  5   
    [3]1  4  7  4  
    [4]2  1  3  3  6
    [5]2  2  4  5  
    [6]3  1  2  2  5
    [7]3  2  1  3
```

In this way I'm able to keep the rest of the data frame intact. The purpose of this is largely for formatting when I ultimately print this (in case anyone is wondering why on earth someone would want to do this).

Admittedly, I'm a beginner. This was a task I used to run through Excel VBA but that process is very taxing on the computer because I run this on a very large data set and it slows everything down too much. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: Similar questions have been asked - but those apply to data frames consisting of just one column (i.e. they do not have to preserve the rest of the row in their replacement) Solutions on those questions would identify rows with the duplicate values in column E, and then replace the values in all the columns with a blank.

Comment: How do you decide which duplicate to keep vs to switch to `""`?

Comment: Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306011/replace-duplicated-elements-with-na-instead-of-removing-them

Comment: @Wen if this is a duplicate, please flag it as such instead of just providing a link

Comment: Thanks @AlexW, I am still new to SO, Will do that in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use duplicated like this:

```
df$E[duplicated(df$E)] <- ""

> df
  A B C D E
1 1 2 5 6 7
2 1 3 6 5  
3 1 4 7 4  
4 2 1 3 3 6
5 2 2 4 5  
6 3 1 2 2 5
7 3 2 1 3
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="   A  B  C  D  E
1  2  5  6  7
1  3  6  5  7 
1  4  7  4  7
2  1  3  3  6
2  2  4  5  6
3  1  2  2  5
3  2  1  3  5",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! I had tried working something similar to that before, but I must have had it out of order.