# Replace consecutive repeated values with NA in list

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I would like to replace consecutively repeated values that are stored in dataframes within lists with NA, see the example below:

```
A = data.frame(matrix( 
c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1), 
  nrow=4, 
  ncol=2))

B = data.frame(matrix( 
  c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1), 
  nrow=4, 
  ncol=2))

myList <- list(A,B)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
  X1 X2
1  1  1
2  2  3
3  3  3
4  1  1

[[2]]
  X1 X2
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  2  3
4  1  1
```

And I am aiming for

```
[[1]]
  X1 X2
1  1  1
2  2  3
3  3  NA
4  1  1

[[2]]
  X1 X2
1  1  1
2  NA 2
3  2  3
4  1  1
```

I imagine this should be relatively straight forward with `lapply`, but I simply do not get there..

Comment: Using [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306011/replace-duplicated-elements-with-na-instead-of-removing-them), loop through list, then through columns.

Comment: `lapply(list, function(x){
    apply(x, 2, function(y){
    return(ifelse(duplicated(y), NA, y))
     })
})`

Comment: I have just edited the question, so that in row 4 further repetitions of values from the same column appear. However, only consecutive values should be replaced. 'duplicated' does not work for this if I am not wrong. Many thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using diff:

```
res <- lapply(myList, function(i)
  data.frame(lapply(i, function(j)
    ifelse(c(FALSE, diff(j) == 0), NA, j)
  )))

res
# [[1]]
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  1
# 2  2  3
# 3  3 NA
# 4  1  1
# 
# [[2]]
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  1
# 2 NA  2
# 3  2  3
# 4  1  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach using lag function from `library(dplyr)`

```
library(dplyr)

  lapply(myList, function(x){
      b = apply(x, 2, function(y){
        c(y[1],ifelse(y == lag(y), NA, y)[2:length(y)])
         })
      return(as.data.frame(b))
    })
```

so if `y` is the same as `lag(y)` return `NA`, else return `y`. But not for the first element of `y` since `lag(y[1])` is `NA`.