# Replace duplicated values with NA by group

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame like so:

```
subject <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5)
day <- c(20, 20, 20 , 20, 20, 40 , 40 , 40 , 40 , 50, 50, 50, 40, 40, 40, 40, 20, 20)

ex <- data.frame(subject, day)
```

Within each subject, I want to change duplicate 'day' to NA:

```
   subject day
1        1  20
2        1  NA
3        1  NA
4        1  NA
5        1  NA
6        2  40
7        2  NA
8        2  NA
9        2  NA
10       3  50
11       3  NA
12       3  NA
13       4  40
14       4  NA
15       4  NA
16       4  NA
17       5  20
18       5  NA
```

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. If you have an additional question, please post a new question, rather than adding them to you original. Cheers

Comment: Simple in `base` R: `ex$day[duplicated(ex)] = NA`

Comment: Related: [Replace duplicated elements with NA, instead of removing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306011/replace-duplicated-elements-with-na-instead-of-removing-them). Note that `duplicated` also accepts a data frame.

Answer (score 6):

```
library(dplyr)
ex %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(day = ifelse(duplicated(day), NA, day)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 18 × 2
#    subject   day
#      <dbl> <dbl>
#  1       1    20
#  2       1    NA
#  3       1    NA
#  4       1    NA
#  5       1    NA
#  6       2    40
#  7       2    NA
#  8       2    NA
#  9       2    NA
# 10       3    50
# 11       3    NA
# 12       3    NA
# 13       4    40
# 14       4    NA
# 15       4    NA
# 16       4    NA
# 17       5    20
# 18       5    NA
```

Comment: No need to group: `mutate(ex, day = replace(day, duplicated(ex), NA))` (or simply `ex$day[duplicated(ex)] = NA`)

Comment: Ah, gotcha---thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

ex %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(day = ifelse(row_number()==1, day, NA_real_)) %>% 
  ungroup()

  subject   day
     <dbl> <dbl>
 1       1    20
 2       1    NA
 3       1    NA
 4       1    NA
 5       1    NA
 6       2    40
 7       2    NA
 8       2    NA
 9       2    NA
10       3    50
11       3    NA
12       3    NA
13       4    40
14       4    NA
15       4    NA
16       4    NA
17       5    20
18       5    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
ex$day <- NA^duplicated(ex) * ex$day
```

-output

```
> ex
   subject day
1        1  20
2        1  NA
3        1  NA
4        1  NA
5        1  NA
6        2  40
7        2  NA
8        2  NA
9        2  NA
10       3  50
11       3  NA
12       3  NA
13       4  40
14       4  NA
15       4  NA
16       4  NA
17       5  20
18       5  NA
```

Comment: And for the mind boggled, perhaps a little educational comment on exponenting NA^, is this a kind of side effect?

Comment: @Chris It's standard exponentiation rules: any nonzero number raised to the power of 0 (here `FALSE` is coerced to 0) is 1; `NA^FALSE == NA^0`. Any number raised to the power of 1 (here `TRUE` is coerced to 1) is the number itself; `NA^TRUE == NA^1`. Thus, it's a golfy way to convert `FALSE` to 1 and `TRUE` to `NA`.

Comment: @Chris Also relevant in `?"^"`: `y ^ 0` [is] 1, _always_.